# Error: Incorrect attribute value type module.network.private_subnets[0] is tuple with 3 elements

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am running into an issue while trying to upgrade from terraform 11 to terraform 12. I was previously using the following syntax to retrieve the 3rd element from a list of ids from a module. The module output is like so:

```
# Subnets
output "private_subnets" {
  description = "List of IDs of private subnets"
  value       = ["${aws_subnet.private.*.id}"]
}
```

Previously, this worked with terraform 11

```
subnet_id              = "${element(module.network.private_subnets,3)}"
```

I thought that I could use the index of 2 to get the same results, but I get the following error:

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on terraformfile.tf line 65, in resource "aws_instance" "myinstance":
  65:   subnet_id              = module.network.private_subnets[2]
    |----------------
    | module.network.private_subnets[2] is tuple with 3 elements
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The currently used value:

```
 value       = ["${aws_subnet.private.*.id}"]
```

produces a **list of lists**. For example,

```
[
  [
    "subnet-0f5b759e80ffcf305",
    "subnet-0500c8c2a40e5b381",
  ],
]
```

If you want to keep using this in that form, later, when you use `element` you have to do following:

```
subnet_id  = element(module.network.private_subnets[0], 3)
```

Alternatively, redefine `private_subnets` to be:

```
 value       = aws_subnet.private.*.id
```

Comment: The output is from an external module that uses an older version of terraform.

Answer (score 3):

The answer from @Marcin holds good but I hit a very similar error in a slightly different situation and I took a different approach to resolve it.

Lets say you have a `aws_security_group_rule` rule and each of the data -sourced item in the list below i.e `data.aws_subnet.app1_subnets.*.cidr_block` and `data.aws_subnet.app2_subnets.*.cidr_block` are a tuple with lets say X elements - You might hit an error -

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on stack.tf line 44, in resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ds_security_group_ingress_rule":
  44:   cidr_blocks = [
  45:     data.aws_subnet.app1_subnets.*.cidr_block,
  46:     data.aws_subnet.app2_subnets.*.cidr_block
  47:   ]
    |----------------
    | data.aws_subnet.app1_subnets.*.cidr_block is tuple with 3 elements
    | data.aws_subnet.app2_subnets.*.cidr_block is tuple with 3 elements

Inappropriate value for attribute "cidr_blocks": element 0: string required.
```

I had to use the `flatten` function to resolve the issue which quite literally flattens the content..

Change the below:

```
cidr_blocks = [
data.aws_subnet.app1_subnets.*.cidr_block,
data.aws_subnet.app2_subnets.*.cidr_block
]
```

as

```
cidr_blocks = flatten([
data.aws_subnet.app1_subnets.*.cidr_block,
data.aws_subnet.app2_subnets.*.cidr_block
])
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue , **flatten** HELPED !! .

the configuration  file looked like this :

```
resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "for-database" {
  name       = "for-database"
  description = "private subnets in different AZs"
  subnet_ids = module.vpc.private_subnets
}
```

**got this error** :

│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   39:   value       =  module.vpc.private_subnets.subnet_count
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.vpc.private_subnets is tuple with 2 elements
│
│ This value does not have any attributes.

**solution**:

```
resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "for-database" {
  name       = "for-database"
  description = "private subnets in different AZs"
  subnet_ids = flatten([module.vpc.private_subnets])
}
```

Answer (score -1):

it was quite difficult for me but i handled it via `flatten` function i took tuple and pass it to flatten function

```
/* Subnets group for DBs */
resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "default" {
  name       = "main"
  subnet_ids = flatten([aws_subnet.PrivateSubnets.*.id])

  tags = {
    Name = "Private Subnet group"
  }
}
```